# Converting a free source control to CM Synergy

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisehg, cm-synergy

My company is using CM Synergy as it's code version control tool, maybe it's my own problem that I can't hanlde this tool very nice. But in my own experience, Hg, Git or SVN is very useful for me. Is there any way to convert a opensource control archive to CM Synergy?

I know there is a way to convert a CM Synergy archive to Git:
https://github.com/emanuelez/PySynergy

Comment: Could you elaborate on your current setup in Git? Are you trying to transfer an initial baseline of your applications or are you wanting to capture entire histories. The latter would be difficult, if even possible. Git and CCM are two different beasts. My condolences on your Synergy adventure.

Comment: I think I'm trying to transfer the entire history, but seems that it's impossible. And I think I've already giving up this idea. btw I use hg as my own code version tool, so git isn't setup properly in my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I had to work with TFS for a while and installed Mercurial/TortoiseHg, too. Then I created a Hg repository in the working copy folder which was already under TFS control. There is no problem with those tools in one folder because the use different control folders (.hg and .tfs), and of course if you don't mess them up in you mind :-) I then worked with Hg as long as possible, and only comitted to TFS when the bugfix/feature was finished.

Perhaps this works with Hg and CM Synergy in the same way.

Comment: Has anybody actually tried this setup with Hg or git? Doesn't this mess up the timestamps of the files when switching branches? CM/Synergy is very sensitive in this matter.

Comment: @harpun Yes, I did. We have Synergy, and I locally have git installed and I work with it, mainly to quickly notice what files changed. but for instance, if I git checkout another branch and then git checkout back to the main branch, Synergy Update will fail because it will consider the files as changed. Couldn't find a solution to this yet. :(

Comment: @splintor: you need two repositories. Repository A is synced with Synergy. You only use a single branch in this repo (i.e. master) in order not to mess up the timestamps as you said. Then in repository B you do the real development. There you can switch branches, work and finally commit/merge to master. Finally in A you pull the changes and commit to Synergy.

Comment: @harpun Thanks, but when I do Update in A to get other people's stuff - how do I get it to B? Does it interfere with my current work? Are you currently working with it successfully?

Comment: @splintor: the trick is to develop on a regular basis, but finally have all the changes merged to the master branch. In A you will just pull the changes from the master branch and synchronize them with Synergy. When you update in A depends strictly on your workflow. In my case, git is used along with feature branches. The sync with Synergy occurs only once for a release. For every merge commit I create a single Synergy task.